# How to trigger js-vue-modal within actions

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm using the [vue-js-modal](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal) library. I also use vuex. How do I trigger open a modal within actions? (as `this.$modals.show('modal-name')` only works within a Vue component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin adds `$modals` to the Vue class prototype, so all you would need to do is import Vue in your store and then emit the event to show the model. For example:

```
// store.js
import Vue from 'vue'
const vm = new Vue()
...
actions: {
    openModal: (context, params) => {
         // do things
         vm.$modals.show('my-modal')
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: it's $modal no $modals